# Calculating Max, Min, and Average Sensor Readings with GridDB Narrow Tables in IoT Project

Tags: griddb

Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm currently working on an IoT project, and I've chosen GridDB as my database to store
time-series data from 5 different sensors. I'm using narrow tables to store sensor readings, each
entry containing the sensor ID, reading value, and a timestamp.
I'm trying to determine the Maximum, Minimum, and Average sensor readings across all 5
sensors within a specific time period. The desired result should include three columns (max,
min, average) and five rows (one for each sensor).

To provide better context, here's the command I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_reading(
sensor_reading_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
sensor_reading_sensor_id STRING NOT NULL,
sensor_reading_read_value DOUBLE NOT NULL
);
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or example queries on how to achieve this in GridDB.